# Getting an Optiplex 790 Desktop FF motherboard working in another case

Tags: motherboard, dell-optiplex

I moved my Dell Optiplex 790 Desktop FF (form factor) motherboard into another case so I can use my EVGA 600 Watt Bronze power supply, but it will not turn on. I do not know where to put the power switch and cannot find it in the [manual](http://clascsg.uconn.edu/download/specs/O790.pdf). On Page 6, it says to put it in 21 but it will not work in any of the slots. The Power Supply, Hard Drive, DVD Drive, Motherboard, CPU, and RAM all worked before moving the motherboard.

(More) [Images](https://mega.nz/#F!nI1n1Yba!HzYMeiVhxSzcNs6mQy405A) [image: Power Switch] [image: Dell Power Switch (Next to RAM)]

Comment: The switch is only going to be used by Dell PSU.  `12V_PWRCONN` and   `POWER` should be enough.  Of course Dell is known not to do anything standard.

Comment: Can you take a full overhead picture of the board you have pictured? I can see the words PWR SW just above the connection, but I can't really see much past that. It also seems like something that is Dell proprietary thing, or a Dell "secret". Maybe a full overhead picture of the board would be nice too.

Comment: @DrZoo It was too large to upload, but you can download it here: https://mega.nz/#F!nI1n1Yba!HzYMeiVhxSzcNs6mQy405A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its correct, Dell does not design their components as standard, the problem could be your generic powersupply not the power buttom

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is an old post and you probably already figured this out but this is a problem that I recently ran into and I think it would be helpful to the next guy if the answer was posted somewhere.

You have to remove the wires from the new 2 pin power switch wire block (release the pins, do not cut them out) then trim them down to fit the dell power switch block,

If we number the dell power pin block...

123
 45_

then the wires from the new switch go orange-1 and white-4. That will make your switch work but you'll still get warnings at boot since it's not dell propriatory setup.